# Error using NVIDIA Compute Visual Profiler

Tags: cuda, profiler

I managed to use visual profiler and get some results. Although there is one application that I can't obtain any results using Visual profiler and get an error like this :

```
Application ".......Release/ProjectName.exe".
Profiler data file ' 'Realease/temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv for application run 0 not found.
```

The way I do it I open Compute Visual Profiler, click session, there I select .exe file and indicate working directory to `Release` folder. Everything seems OK, the application runs 18 times obtaining good results, but after that I got the error as I wrote.

Comment: sometimes vp has difficulty with applications that have large numbers of threadblocks or many many kernel calls.  If you have an application like this, see if you can scale down the problem to a smaller number of threadblocks or kernel calls, to see if you get better results.

Comment: What CUDA toolkit are you using?

Comment: Cuda toolkit 4.2. I am not sure if this might be the case with too many kernel calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think there probably are lines such as `getchar()` and `system("pause")` in you program.

These types of lines should be removed when using the profiler.

Comment: What evidence do you have for this?